# Template superclass constructor called when converting to base

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, c++17, linear-algebra

I'm trying to write a utility header for a linear algebra program, it's mainly for learning so I'm more concerned about ease than efficiency.

Anyways, the idea is that I have a `Matrix` type, and a `Vector` type which inherits from `Matrix`. Because I want to add some specialized function especially for the 3D case, without rewriting the whole class, I also have a `_Vector` class which is meant to be inherited by both the general and special type.

Here is a minimal example of the failure:
(fails.hpp)

```
#include <string>

template <int M, int N, typename FloatType = double>
class Matrix {
public:
  inline Matrix() : data{0}{}
protected:
  FloatType data[M * N];
};

template <int DIM, typename FloatType>
class _Vector : public Matrix<DIM, 1, FloatType> {
public:
  template <typename ...FloatTypes>
  inline constexpr _Vector(const FloatTypes... values)
    : Matrix<sizeof...(FloatTypes), 1, FloatType>()
  {
    int i = 0;
    ((Matrix<DIM, 1, FloatType>::data[i++] = values), ...);
  }

  inline FloatType operator [](const int index) {
    return Matrix<DIM, 1, FloatType>::data[index];
  }


  inline operator std::string () const {
    std::string tmp = "[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
      tmp += std::to_string(Matrix<DIM, 1, FloatType>::data[i]) + " ";
    }
    tmp += "]\n";
    return tmp;
  }
};

template<int DIM, typename FloatType = double>
class Vector : _Vector<DIM, FloatType> {
  template <typename ...FloatTypes>
  inline constexpr Vector(const FloatTypes... values) : _Vector<DIM, FloatType>(values...) {}
};

template <typename ...FloatTypes>
Vector(const FloatTypes...) -> Vector<sizeof...(FloatTypes), std::common_type_t<FloatTypes...>>;

template <typename FloatType>
class Vector<3, FloatType> : public _Vector<3, FloatType> {
public:
  FloatType& x = Matrix<3, 1, FloatType>::data[0];
  FloatType& y = Matrix<3, 1, FloatType>::data[1];
  FloatType& z = Matrix<3, 1, FloatType>::data[2];

  template <typename ...FloatTypes>
  inline constexpr Vector(const FloatTypes... values) : _Vector<3, FloatType>(values...) {}

  // cross product
  inline Vector operator ^(_Vector<3, FloatType>& other) {
    Vector V;
    V.x = y * other[2] - z * other[1];
    V.y = z * other[0] - x * other[2];
    V.z = x * other[1] - y * other[0];
    return V;
  }
};
```

(main.cpp)

```
#include <fails.hpp>
//#include <works.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Vector v1 = { 1., 2., 3. };
  Vector v2 = { 3., 2., 1. };

  std::cout << (std::string)(v1 ^ v2);
}
```

What I don't understand is that if I remove the inheritance from the `Matrix` type, it fixes the issue:
(works.hpp)

```
#include <string>

template <int DIM, typename FloatType>
class _Vector {
public:
  template <typename ...FloatTypes>
  inline constexpr _Vector(const FloatTypes... values)
    {
      int i = 0;
      ((data[i++] = values), ...);
    }

  inline FloatType operator [](const int index) {
    return data[index];
  }


  inline operator std::string () const {
    std::string tmp = "[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
      tmp += std::to_string(data[i]) + " ";
    }
    tmp += "]\n";
    return tmp;
  }
protected:
  FloatType data[DIM];
};

template<int DIM, typename FloatType = double>
class Vector : _Vector<DIM, FloatType> {
  template <typename ...FloatTypes>
  inline constexpr Vector(const FloatTypes... values) : _Vector<DIM, FloatType>(values...) {}
};

template <typename ...FloatTypes>
Vector(const FloatTypes...) -> Vector<sizeof...(FloatTypes), std::common_type_t<FloatTypes...>>;

template <typename FloatType>
class Vector<3, FloatType> : public _Vector<3, FloatType> {
public:
  FloatType& x = Vector<3, FloatType>::data[0];
  FloatType& y = Vector<3, FloatType>::data[1];
  FloatType& z = Vector<3, FloatType>::data[2];

  template <typename ...FloatTypes>
  inline constexpr Vector(const FloatTypes... values) : _Vector<3, FloatType>(values...) {}

  // cross product
  inline Vector operator ^(_Vector<3, FloatType>& other) {
    Vector V;
    V.x = y * other[2] - z * other[1];
    V.y = z * other[0] - x * other[2];
    V.z = x * other[1] - y * other[0];
    return V;
  }
};
```

When I compile with `g++ -I. main.cpp -std=c++17` I get this output:

```
n file included from main.cpp:1:
./fails.hpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr _Vector<DIM, FloatType>::_Vector(const FloatTypes ...) [with FloatTypes = {}; int DIM = 3; FloatType = double]’:
./fails.hpp:54:88:   required from ‘Vector<3, FloatType> Vector<3, FloatType>::operator^(_Vector<3, FloatType>&) [with FloatType = double]’
main.cpp:9:35:   required from here
./fails.hpp:58:12:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘V.Vector<3, double>::Vector<>()’
./fails.hpp:16:51: error: type ‘Matrix<0, 1, double>’ is not a direct base of ‘_Vector<3, double>’
   16 |     : Matrix<sizeof...(FloatTypes), 1, FloatType>()
      |
```

I don't know how the inheritance changed the situation at all but it now seems like the `_Vector` class constructor is called for some reason (with wrong template parameters at that). I don't know what to search for, so if you can explain why it causes this issue and in general what type of problem this is I'd be very grateful.
Thank you!

Comment: Off-topic, but be aware that `_Vector` is a reserved identifier (starts with an underscore followed by a capital letter), your program exhibits undefined behavior by using it.

Comment: Oh thanks! I changed it, but sadly the problem remains :(

Comment: `_Vector` doesn't have a default constructor, and so neither does `Vector`, and then `Vector V;` fails to compile. By using `Matrix<sizeof...(FloatTypes), 1, FloatType>` in the initializer list, you effectively require that `sizeof...(FloatTypes) == DIM`, and preclude an empty list of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_Vector<int DIM, typename FloatType>` inherits `Matrix<DIM, FloatType>`, but its constructor uses `sizeof...(FloatTypes)` as the first template parameter of `Matrix`

```
template <int DIM, typename FloatType>
class _Vector : public Matrix<DIM, 1, FloatType>
 public:
   template <typename ...FloatTypes>
   constexpr _Vector(const FloatTypes... values)
     : Matrix<sizeof...(FloatTypes), 1, FloatType>();
};
```

This means that when `DIM` is not equal to `sizeof...(FloatTypes)`, your `_Vector` initializes a base that does *not* inherit from it, you should define the constructor as

```
template <typename ...FloatTypes>
constexpr _Vector(const FloatTypes... values)
  : Matrix<DIM, 1, FloatType>();
```

Comment: Or drop the initializer list altogether, as calling the default constructor of the base class is going to happen anyway.

Comment: Wow thanks! I don't understand how sizeof...(FloatTypes) and DIM can be different, but the change works!

Comment: @Hadron `Vector V;` is equivalent to `Vector<3, FloatType> V{};`, calling the constructor with `sizeof...(FloatTypes) == 0`. Obviously, `DIM != 0`